# How to add the username to the docker group?

Tags: docker

I want to avoid typing sudo every time I run the docker command, So I try to add my username to the docker group. The username That I employ is my DockerID:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker ${DockerID}
```

However, the output is:

```
Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN
```

I really don't understand the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the username instead of `${DockerID}` or just use `$USER`